# How to set Devise to require one of email or username to be populated for saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I followed this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Which works.  So now I can login with either :username and :password or :email and :password.

However, when I am creating accounts in the console, if I leave email blank, I get a validation error.  Apparently email is still required to create a user.

I'd like to be able to create a user just using :username and :password, or :email and :password.

Comment: Have you override find_first_by_auth_conditions method in user model?

Comment: No I have not.  Is there a link to some documentation about which methods to override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try adding the following to your User model:

```
def email_required?
  false
end
```

You may also need to create a migration which will allow email column on users table to be null ( in case it is not null-allowed column already):

```
change_column :users, :email, :string, :null => true
```

**EDIT**:

All you have left to do is to ensure that at least username or email is present. You can do it by setting the following validation statement:

```
validate :username_or_email_is_present

def username_or_email_is_present
  if self.username.blank && self.email.blank?
    errors.add(:base, "Email or Username must be set")
  end
end
```

Comment: I can get past the validations by commenting out validatable in the model.  I have also set the migration to allow nulls.  But how do I set the condition that you must have either email and password OR username and password?

Comment: got you, refined my answer as requested.